# How to format body for form-data header

Tags: flutter, dart

This might be probably already answered question but I can not find one. How do we format data body for form-data http response? I tried to encode it to json but that didn't work with error 
`Unhandled Exception: Multipart: Boundary not found`

```
  Future<void> createProfile() async {
    final body = {
      "firstName": "first",
      "lastName": "last",
      "image": "path-to-image"
    };
    try {
      final http.Response response = await http.post(APIPath.createProfile(),
          headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $token","Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
          body: json.encode(body)); //<-- this doesn't work
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode != 201) {
        throw HttpException(jsonResponse["error"]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flutter Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html)

```
var uri = Uri.parse('https://example.com/create');
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
  ..headers['authorization'] = 'auth header value'
  ..fields['user'] = 'nweiz@google.com'
  ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'package', 'build/image.png',
      contentType: MediaType('image', '*')));
var response = await request.send();
if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!');
```

Comment: Yes... I've been there.. I just can not figure out how to also send Authorization header with it. also media type in my case is image and the documentation doesn't really say anything about image

Comment: `...headers['authorization'] = 'the auth header value';`
just use this line to add your header.
Run the code and let me know what happens next...

Comment: great.. thanks.. that seems to work.. I still have trouble with images... How to we let upload all types of images?

Comment: try this one
`MediaType('image', '*')`

Comment: Oh... great.. thanks... can you please add it to your answer just in case comments gets deleted.. i believe this might be helpful for others as well

Comment: I will do that for sure!